# Can't find hg-buildpackage

Tags: package-management, deb, mercurial

It was suggested I use hg-buildpackage to build my Ubuntu packages because it will ignore my .hg folder and files.

However I can't seem to find it in the Ubuntu 10.10 repos.

How can I get hg-buildpackage on Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu appears to have transitioned from [hg-buildpackage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hg-buildpackage&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) to [mercurial-buildpackage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mercurial-buildpackage&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) with the release of Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid).

The [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/mercurial-buildpackage.1.html) for mercurial-buildpackage explains that it "originates  from  John  Goerzen’s  hg-buildpackage," but since it is not an exact replacement there is no [transitional package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20377/what-exact-purpose-have-transitional-packages) to guide users who are looking for hg-buildpackage by name.