# How Reliable is Virtual Machine GCC Binaries

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, deb, gcc

I have an app which I need to generate the following:
Ubuntu 32/64 bits and the same to Windows. Now I have 64Bits Ubuntu 13.04 and I have Virtual Box with 13.04 32bits on the same machine. How reliable is the file produced by Virtuabox? Can it be uploaded for customers to use it?

I currently have no other machine (its coming and so it will finally sort out, but meanwhile I need to get it sorted for now)

How reliable is Virtual machine binaries especially when run on native machine?
I have posts like this to make me worry a bit! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916145/c-doubles-precision-virtual-machines-and-gcc

Comment: Question is unclear: what do you mean by reliable?  Running gcc ( or any program ) under a virtual machine will produce the same results as on a real machine.

Comment: @psusi if you check the link, he's asking if he will have some kind of unexpected behavior when using Virtual Machines. (In that specific case there was a bug that the same code produced different results in a real and a virtual machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concerns are overestimated:

> Upgrading virtualbox to version 4.1.8r75467 resolved the issue.

Ubuntu have more than 3 years and VirtualBox is 2 (3?) versions ahead. So, there shouldn't be problems.

---

BTW, you don't need a 32-bit machine to compile 32-bits binaries, since Ubuntu supports multiarch, you only need to install the 32-bit counter-part of the libraries, example:

You need to compile something using openssl in 32 and 64 bits, you can use `export CFLAGS=-m32` or `-m32` (depends the compiler, I'm using `gcc`), but, what about the libraries? Install them using `:i386` in apt

```
 sudo apt-get install openssl-dev:i386
 gcc -m32 -o program program.c
```

That will produce your 32-bit program in a 64-bit system.

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1272357/792066
- https://askubuntu.com/a/359184/169736

Comment: Well are you saying that Binaries produced by VM will run fine on Native machine?

Comment: Also can I use the same machine to make 32 and 64 bits by changing compiler flag and installing 32Bit libs?

Comment: 1) Will not be affected by *that* issue. 2) Yes.