# Running Binding of Isaac on 64-bit?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, games, dependencies

This is a re-post of a question I've put [here](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:45563) to no avail. I've been using Ubuntu for quite a while now, but my knowledge is limited. Please bear with me! :)

This issue revolves around the recent removal of ia32-libs in Ubuntu 13.10, and the game Binding of Isaac which depends on it -

> I recently purchased the game as part of the Humble Bundle, excited that it is now available for Linux. However I have been unable to run either the 64 or 32 bit versions on my Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit system.
>
> I cannot install the 64 bit version, as it depends on the ia32-libs package, which was removed in 13.10.
>
> I am able to install the 32 bit version after installing all dependencies separately, but when starting the game I get the errors "libssl3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", "Error: initialising plugin." and "Error: initialising projector". I presume these all come when the game tries to load libraries that aren't there.
>
> Both of the above instances occur when trying to install the game via a .deb file.

When I say "installing all dependencies", I mean installing every package listed as a dependency in the info attached to the .deb file.

Has anybody got any ideas about this?

Comment: Are you missing `libnss3:i386` in the list of packages you've installed?

Comment: this got me a step further, I get a window and no error messages. But the window freezes and shows nothing. Starting to think this is too deep an issue for me to fix?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the easy way of downloading all of the 32 dependencies was taken out by the developers. Now if a application from the repo needs 32 libs it installs them automatically as it needs them. Apparently this leaves applications that are installed from .deb files in a world of dependency hell. You'll have to figure out the packages you need and install them yourself; one at a fricken time.

You can do this from the terminal with `apt-get` and `:i386` on the end.

example:
`sudo apt-get install libmpg123-0:i386`

You can read more about it here: [How do you run a 32-bit program on a 64-bit version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359156/how-do-you-run-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: thanks, I'll try this tomorrow. What does this do exactly? Install the 32-bit version of all packages in the future?

Comment: That is not required since 12.04. Ubuntu is MultiArch capable already, and one can install i386 packages by installing `package:i386` with apt-get. Also, this isn't an answer, but should be a comment on the question, as it asks to try something, rather than provide a specific answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3:i386
```

Comment: please give some explanation as to why one would run the command. and on a side note, Ubuntu 13.10 is not supported anymore.