# App can't find libs even though they exist

Tags: 14.04, libraries

I'm trying to launch an application (lets call it test), but it fails giving the following error:

```
./test
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Although this library does exist:

```
locate libuuid.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

It also can be found when using `sudo ldconfig -v` under the same folder.

Running ldd on the app gives the following info:

```
ldd test 
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76fe000)
libsteam_api.so => ./libsteam_api.so (0xf7665000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => ./libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xf74ba000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf736d000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0xf730d000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf72f3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf72d7000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf72ce000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf72c8000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7282000)
libuuid.so.1 => not found
libc++.so.1 => ./libc++.so.1 (0xf71d8000)
libcxxrt.so => ./libcxxrt.so (0xf71b9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7008000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf6feb000)
libiconv.so.2 => ./libiconv.so.2 (0xf6f07000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf6e1e000)
libasound.so.2 => not found
libssl.so.1.0.0 => ./libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xf6dc7000)
libopenal.so.1 => not found
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf6da5000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0xf6d8d000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf6d7a000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf6d75000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf6d6f000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xf6d6c000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xf6d54000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xf6d4e000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0xf6d49000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0xf6d45000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0xf6d3e000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0xf6d3b000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf6d35000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0xf6d27000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76ff000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf6d23000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf6d1c000)
```

So I'm missing 3 libraries in total, although all of them can be found using `locate` or `sudo ldconfig -v`.

I've tried using `sudo ldconfig`, and it did not change anything.
I've also tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory of library.

Comment: Tip for the future: *locate* and *ldconfig* are giving you paths containing `x86_64-linux-gnu`, *ldd* instead is giving paths containing `i386-linux-gnu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost sure that you get this error because you try to run a 32-bit (`libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6`) executable on a 64-bit (`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1`) operating system. Run `file test` to check this. Thus, the following Q&A may help you:

- [How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/q/454253/147044)

Comment: It seems you are correct:

`file test` 


`test: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.2.32, BuildID[sha1]=8b62606c74c33517d5184ab14c3f80bd49b39f82, stripped`

Although I did what the top answer suggested in your link, I still have the same problem.

Comment: @WindBlade See also http://askubuntu.com/q/359156/147044 or http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12956/37944

Comment: I solved the problem by installing the missing packages with `:i386` suffix. Thanks for the help! Although now, when I try launching the application it says: `segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./test`. Could you point me the right direction to solve this?

Comment: @WindBlade If I would be you I will try to recompile that `test` on a 64 bit system. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2346806/2353900