# Can't understand difference between liblapack3 and liblapack3gf

Tags: 12.04, apt, libraries, shared-library

I need to install the lapack library in an ubuntu computer for linking to a code I am developing.

I have been told to `apt-get install liblapack3`, but the only one I found is `liblapack3gf`. My list of apt says `liblapack3gf - library of linear algebra routines 3 - shared version`, but the person who told me to install it has `liblapack3 - Library of linear algebra routines 3 - shared version` and `liblapack3gf - Transitional package for liblapack3`.

What is a transitional package? Should I install `lapack3gf` or download directly from lapack page? should I also install `liblapack-dev`?

Comment: Transitional packages Q/A: [What exact purpose have transitional packages?](http://askubuntu.com/q/20377/32239)

Comment: You'll need the `liblapack-dev` in order to link your compiled object files together with the `-llapack` switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of a transitional package as a shortcut to another (desired) package. The transitional package does not contain anything but metadata that indicates that this package depends on the desired package so that the desired package will be installed when you will be trying to install the transitional package.

In you case as it says,

```
liblapack3gf - library of linear algebra routines 3 - shared version
```

As far as the description is concerned you are good to install `liblapack3gf`.

Whereas in other person's computer when he will try to install `liblapack3gf`, as it is a transitional package for `liblapack3 - Library of linear algebra routines 3 - shared version` the following will pop up:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
   liblapack3
```