# How to make APT/Aptitude prefer a more recent virtual package over a real one

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, aptitude

I've recently built a package which provides multiple virtual ones, more specifically snmp which provides libsnmp-base, libsnmp30 and so on:

```
 - Version: 5.8~git20160427.8d07349f-14
 - Depends: ...
 - Provides:
   snmp,libsnmp-base,libsnmp-dev,libsnmp30,python-snmp,snmpd,snmptrapd,tkmib
 - Conflicts:
   libsnmp-base,libsnmp-dev,libsnmp30,python-snmp,snmpd,snmptrapd,tkmib
 - Replaces:
   libsnmp-base,libsnmp-dev,libsnmp30,python-snmp,snmpd,snmptrapd,tkmib
```

It is installed on my system & provided on my online PPA.
When I try to install another package (php7.0-snmp) which depends on libsnmp30 & libsnmp-base, APT offers me the option of uninstalling snmp in order to install the required dependencies.

It seems that APT always prefers real packages over virtual ones, despite the facts that:

- the virtual ones have a more recent version
- they are already installed

Aptitude offers more solutions, but none involves the preferred & most logical one: keep snmp because it already offers the most recent needed dependencies:

```
sudo aptitude install php7.0-snmpThe following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsnmp30{a} php7.0-snmp 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 832 kB of archives. After unpacking 3,382 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 snmp : Conflicts: libsnmp30 but 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:               
1)     snmp                                       

     Install the following packages:              
2)     libsnmp-base [5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4 (xenial)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libsnmp30 [Not Installed]                          
2)     php7.0-snmp [Not Installed]                        

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:                                           
1)     libsnmp-base [5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4 (xenial)]                             

     Downgrade the following packages:                                         
2)     snmp [5.8~git20160427.8d07349f-14 (now) -> 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4 (xenial)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

*** No more solutions available ***
```

How can I install php7.0-snmp **without having to uninstall snmp**?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual packages can't help you here. From [the Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-virtual):

> If a relationship field has a version number attached, only real
>   packages will be considered to see whether the relationship is
>   satisfied (or the prohibition violated, for a conflict or breakage).
>   In other words, if a version number is specified, this is a request to
>   ignore all Provides for that package name and consider only real
>   packages. The package manager will assume that a package providing
>   that virtual package is not of the "right" version. A Provides field
>   may not contain version numbers, and the version number of the
>   concrete package which provides a particular virtual package will not
>   be considered when considering a dependency on or conflict with the
>   virtual package name.

One way out is to create minimal packages for each of the provided packages, which just depend on your actual `snmp` package ([transitional packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/20377/158442)). They'll be of a higher version and preferred automatically.

Comment: OK, but there is no version number attached to any of the relationship field, and the policy stating "the version number of the concrete package which provides a particular virtual package will not be considered when considering a dependency on or conflict with the virtual package name" does not make any sense and should be changed.

Comment: @jean-christophe Check the depends for php7.0-snmp