# Install specific NVIDIA driver package and not have it upgrade via transitional package

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, amazon-ec2

Due to this bug [1674930](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-367/+bug/1674930) my Amazon G2 and P2 instances have stopped working correctly.
I need the 367 driver.  When you attempt to install 367, it says it is actually installing the 375 driver which is incompatible with the G2 and P2 hardware.  The previous 367 version ran fine.

When I run `apt-cache search nvidia-367`
It shows it as being a "Transitional package for nvidia-375".  What does that mean?  I expected when I install 367 it would install 367 not 375.
How do I lock it at 367?

Naturally I have tried installing nvidia-361, but that claims to be a transitional package to 367 which as you guessed is a transitional package to 375 and so no matter which one is chosen it ends up trying to install 375 which is broken for me.

Is there a way to stop it transitioning and just stop at the driver I choose?  I tried `apt-mark hold nvidia-367` which did not work.

Any options appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A "transitional package" might not be something that could actually be installed; see [What exact purpose have transitional packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20377/what-exact-purpose-have-transitional-packages)

I don't know about it but maybe there's a different source for the exact version you need.