# Cannot downgrade nvidia-driver-440 to nvidia-driver-430 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, downgrade

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.2` and I updated the nvidia driver to `440` using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`.

Unfortunately, after this update, the performance that I obtain using the [NVIDIA Optical Flow SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/opticalflow-sdk) are worse than before. For this reason, I would like to roll back to my previous driver version that is `430.50`.

I already tried with `435` and the performance are the same as `440`.

My problem is that, whatever I tried according to old posts, the system still installs the `440` instead of `430`.

The output of `apt policy nvidia-driver-430` is

```
nvidia-driver-430:                                                                                                                                                                            
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Version table:
     440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                                                      
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Indeed, if I try to install the driver using the usually suggested recipe

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430
sudo reboot
```

the version `440` gets installed.

How can I restore that specific version of the driver?

A very similar question that I found is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896236/install-specific-nvidia-driver-package-and-not-have-it-upgrade-via-transitional). However, a solution was not provided.

Edit:
Just in case, I want to confirm that I already tried adding the `graphics-drivers` ppa.

Comment: One possible way to install old nvidia drivers `430` would be to manually download them from nvidia website and install them in one-user mode (root). Just make sure You don't have any other nvidia drivers installed before doing that.

Comment: Unless you have the old debs, not possible anymore. [430 is now a transitional package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/nvidia-driver-430) (also the case for the PPA)

Comment: To add to @MichalPrzybylowicz 's answer, try searching for driver on this link [nvidia driver advanced search](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx)

Comment: Finally solved. I purged `nvidia*` and then downloaded all the debs from [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-430/430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2/+build/17953156) page. Rebooted and finally had the required version of the driver.

Comment: @user2768957 you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I tried installing those linked packages but couldn't get the DKMS modules to compile against kernel 5.4.0. For me, 440 causes random screen lockups every few days, and my WebGL performance has gone through the floor. I guess I'm stuck on 440 now.